# Update HTML value, but ignore class inside the current HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to update the HTML in an element through Jquery. But there's a class in there that I don't want to be touched. Here's an example. I'd like to update the hello text but I want to keep the .arrow class in tact. Is there a way to do without having to add the .arrow html inside the jquery

My pen: http://codepen.io/omarel/pen/mRExvb

HTML

```
 <div class="contactfield">hello
   <div class="arrow">
     <img src="images/arrow.png" />
   </div>
 </div>
```

JQuery

```
$('.contactfield').click(function (event) {
    $(this).html('test'); 
});
```

I know that I could do this, but it feels clunky:

```
 $('.contactfield').click(function (event) {
    $(this).html('test<div class="arrow"><img src="images/arrow.png" /></div>'); 
});
```

Comment: Put your text that says "hello" in its own element like a <div> and give that element a class.  That way you can just target the text and not affect anything else.  Also, you can use .text instead of .html to just change the text.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you don't need to update whole html in '.contactfield'

plase use this:

```
<div class="contactfield"><span class="dynamic">hello</span>
   <div class="arrow">
     <img src="images/arrow.png" />
   </div>
 </div>

$('.contactfield').click(function (event) {
    $(this).find('.dynamic').html('test'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could clone it; that way you don't have to add a `<span>` around `hello`

```
jQuery

$('.contactfield').on('click', function(e){
  var arrow = $('.arrow').clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
  $(this).html('test' + arrow);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to just change the text you could access the [textNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) that wraps the text. Otherwise if you can change the markup do as others have suggested and wrap the text in a `<span>` or some other tag

```
$('.contactfield').click(function (event) {
  $(this)
    .contents()
    .filter((i,node) => node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)[0]
    .nodeValue = "test"
});
```